# Delete a single phone type number from a contact

Tags: android, cursor, android-contacts, phone-number

When a one of the contact have multiple numbers, for example:

> Display name: GuessWho 
>  TYPE = home 
>  Number = homeNumber
>   
>  TYPE = mobile 
>  Number = mobileNumber 
>  TYPE = other 
>   Number = otherNumber ...

in conclusion ... one from [those](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html).

How I can remove a TYPE with number from this contact ( let's say "mobile" )? I have to update it using the userID acquired from the previous query, or how?
I just need to delete a single TYPE with number, other field of the contact must remain intact.

I am using this piece of code for obtaining contact :

```
int indexName = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int indexNumber = c
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
    int indexType = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE);
    int indexID = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID);

String name = c.getString(indexName);
        String number = c.getString(indexNumber);
        String type = c.getString(indexType); 
        String typeStored = (String) Phone.getTypeLabel(mContext.getResources(), Integer.parseInt(type), "");
        Log.i("TYPE READED : ", typeStored);
        String id = c.getString(indexID);
```

where c is the cursor of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each number from same contact has it's own ID. You should use it for deleting. But you also need contact ID. You can get it using this line of code:

```
contactID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
```

Then you delete the number using following code:

```
Cursor cur = contentResolver.query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, 
            new String[]{RawContacts._ID},
            RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?", 
            new String[] {contactID.toString()}, null);
    int rowId=0;;
    if(cur.moveToFirst()){
        rowId = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(RawContacts._ID));
    }

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    String selectPhone = Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + 
                         Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " + 
                         Phone._ID + " = ?";
    String[] phoneArgs = new String[] { Integer.toString(rowId), 
                                        Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, 
                                        ID.toString()};

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(selectPhone, phoneArgs).build());
    try {
        contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: i suppose "contentResolver" is from "myContext.getContentResolver()" where myContext is the context?

Comment: Yes. It is part of my code and I didn't change the notation :) I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly ...and if i want to update instead of delete a number with a given id?

Comment: `ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
  String selectPhone = Data._ID + " = ?";
  String[] phoneArgs = new String[] { ID.toString() };
  ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withSelection(selectPhone, phoneArgs)
    .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, phoneNo)
    .build());
  try {
   contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
  } catch (RemoteException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }`
This is just for updating number

Comment: mmh it doesn't work in my application ... "ID.toString()" is the number id to update, and phoneNo the new number?

Comment: I get no errors, but numbers don't change ... for deleting no problem, but for update nothing happens

Comment: this is what i actually do: 1) read all contat's list, if the number start with a given prefix, i add the user in a given arraylist ( let's say prefixedUsersList ), else i add in a second array ( let's say standardUsersList )2) for each user in prefixedUserList u1 i compare with every user in standardUserList u2, (after remove the prefix ) if numbers are equals, i delete the number with the first code you give me ( all works ), else i update with second code ( but don't update )

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you put contacts or their numbers in ArrayList? Can the sam contact let's say "John Doe" be in both lists?

Comment: I use my "User" class, where i store many information i need in other part of the program too, like display name, phone number, phone id, prefix type ... then when i need to compare i extract what i need with getters methods, i try with "88888" too as new Number, just to see if something wrong in my code, but still doesn't update

Comment: But you will still have two numbers for that user.One updated and one not

Comment: here is how i do: http://pastebin.com/FWwyAnfy if i'm in the situation of using update's code, there are no duplicates number. Let's make a concrete example: i have 4 numbers ( the given prefix is 4146 ) 1 --> 4146 123123  2--> 123123 3--> 89078 4--> 4146 888 . Ok, now number 1 will be deleted ( without prefix is equal then 2 ), 2 remain same, 3 remain same, 4 have to be updated in 888, but nothing happen

Comment: `updateContactByNumberId(mContext, u1.getContactId(), newNumber);`

It looks like you are using contact ID not phone ID. You should use phone ID

Comment: shame on me <.< just questioning about how many times i read again and again the whole code without notice that part! by the way, i really thank you, you were really nice!

Comment: New welcome. It won't be the last time you watch at some piece of code for ages and don't see some stupid mistake :)

Comment: Make sure to init rowId to -1, not 0 to avoid overwriting row 0 in case no result is found.

Answer (score -1):

The code to delete is a little long, the below does what it should with less lines of code

```
public static void deleteContact(ContentResolver contactHelper, String number) {
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    String[] args = new String[] { String.valueOf(getContactID(contactHelper, number)) };
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI).withSelection(RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?", args).build());
    try {
        contactHelper.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```